# angularjs score counter not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, counter

Please take a look at this.

http://plnkr.co/edit/i4B0Q2ZGiuMlogvwujpg?p=preview

```
<input type="radio" name="op_0" ng-value="true" ng-model="n1"> True
<input type="radio" name="op_0" ng-value="false" ng-model="n2"> False
<input type="radio" name="op_0" ng-value="true" ng-model="n3"> True
<input type="radio" name="op_0" ng-value="false" ng-model="n4"> False
```

Why are two radio buttons  selected with a single click? 
Why is the score value not increasing or decreasing?

Comment: Why `ng-model` is same for all?

Comment: All four buttons are bound to the same model. Why is that?

Comment: In addition to the comments already made, your if statements in your controller are evaluated the first time the controller is called and that's it.  You need events on clicking the radio buttons to increment the score.

Comment: Edited . but why is the score value is not increasing?

http://plnkr.co/edit/i4B0Q2ZGiuMlogvwujpg?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

To have all of your radio buttons in the same group they should all have the same name. It is the value that should be different in each one. If they don't have the same name, selecting one won't cause the others to de-select.

```
app.controller('aCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.s = 0;

  $scope.updateScore = function(val){
    if(val == 'true'){
      $scope.s += 1;
    }
    if(val == 'false'){
      $scope.s += -0.5;
    }
  }

});

 <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-8">
        <input type="radio" ng-click="updateScore('true')" name="op_0" ng-value="true" ng-model="n1"> True
        <input type="radio" ng-click="updateScore('false')" name="op_0" ng-value="false" ng-model="n2"> False
        <input type="radio" ng-click="updateScore('true')" name="op_0" ng-value="true" ng-model="n3"> True
        <input type="radio" ng-click="updateScore('false')" name="op_0" ng-value="false" ng-model="n4"> False
      </div>
```

Comment: Score value is not increasing. please take a look
http://plnkr.co/edit/i4B0Q2ZGiuMlogvwujpg?p=preview

Comment: but here it is woking without ng-change. 

http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview